# Finding a template RNN for time series analysis

Tags: tensorflow, time-series, lstm, rnn, gru

I would like to create a RNN, that uses one (A) or several time series (with the same length, A, B, C...) as an input and creates another time series (Z) as an output from that .
Basically all time series are derived from on time series, so their relationship that can be expressed mathematically. ex. B = dA/dt, ... C = moving mean(B)

For training I want to feed the NN with the input and output time series, which I can create with a simulation with known parameters, so that I know the output is correct.

I am new to working with neural networks and couldn't find a NN that seemed to do a similar job. Does somebody have a NN in mind that could do the job?

I asked chatGPT, which said that simple RNNs with or without LSTM or GRU cells could do the job.

Any ideas?